# How many $k$-regular bipartite graphs can I make given $n$ distinct vertices?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I'm attempting to solve a problem that I think can be solved best with graph theory. I know very little regarding graph theory, so excuse any misuse of vocabulary (which I only picked up in the last hour or so).

As the title states, given a set of $n$ distinct vertices and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, I'm trying to find how many $k$-regular bipartite graphs I can make. If it's significantly simpler, in the problem I'm trying to solve, $k = 1$.

Even if you straight up give the answer, I would not mind references, literature, and other learning material. I've always found graph theory to be interesting, and I think this is a good way to break into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a matching. That is, each vertex is paired up with exactly one other vertex. If $n$ is odd, then this is not possible for $k = 1$. Note that the Handshake Lemma states that the sum of the vertex degrees is twice the number of edges. So $nk = 2E$. If $k = 1$ and $n$ is odd, then $nk$ is not even.

So suppose $n$ is even. If your graph is complete (all vertices are adjacent), we stat by choosing our first two vertices to match. This can be done in $\binom{n}{2}$ ways. That is, choose the first vertex. Then there are $n-1$ remaining vertices to match it with. Since we could have chosen the second vertex first, order doesn't matter so we divide out by $2$. We repeat for the remaining $n-2$ vertices. The formula is:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n/2} \binom{n - 2i}{2}$$

This assumes $n$ is even.

If you have a more specific case, the count will be more restrictive.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29